# Safely searching elasticsearch from client-side?

Tags: jquery, database, security, elasticsearch, client-side

If my elasticsearch could be called directly from jQuery it would be much faster and simpler. I currently have a proxy in the middle of my static site and ES cluster.

I have been looking at [Search Guard](https://floragunn.com/) from another answer on here but many features of this wouldn't work e.g. IP blocking as if it was a jQuery script it would be called from my static site visitors IP. Likewise if I have a password and put it in a jQuery script the user would see it.

I have also tried going further up the chain and adding read-only block in my elasticsearch.yml but this doesn't feel like much of a defense on its own.

Is there any way of safely allowing my ES cluster (via URL) to be searched directly from a client-side JS/jQuery script? It would be fantastic if I could get rid of this proxy VM in between.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to implement, means, what do you mean by "safely searching"? Do you want to implement access permissions on index-level? If so, what would be the user's credentials? Please describe your use case in more detail so I can think of a solution. Disclaimer: I work for floragunn, makers of Search Guard.