# Safely searching elasticsearch from client-side JS?

Tags: javascript, angular, elasticsearch

If my elasticsearch could be called directly from Angular then it would be much faster and simpler. I currently have a proxy in the middle of my static site and ES cluster. Is there any way to secure my APi call to elasticsearch like tokenization or something?

I am facing the exact same issue described here. i cant find any valid answers for the question. That's why I am re-posting this.([Safely searching elasticsearch from client-side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47001569/safely-searching-elasticsearch-from-client-side))

Comment: You need an intermediate authorization layer.

Comment: @apokryfos you mean we cannot avoid the middleware? or authorization layer at ES end?

Comment: You can't avoid the middleware if you want a per-user authorization check.

Comment: Trying to get data from database to client side directly will put the load on client device, so; it's not a good idea.